# Trouble trying to use getJSON in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to implement AJAX call method into my website using codeigniter, the reason why i want to use AJAX so i can get live updates from the database

The click button works and displays all of the JSON data but the issue is when i try and display a specific array it does not recognize it, it seems to be iterating through every single character.

Also another wierd thing is when the alert is being called i can see the html and head tags
**I want to be able to print specific arrays for example the array id"**

Things i have done to try and work it out

- i have alerted the datatype and found out it was a string
- i have managed to get ajax to work in regular PHP rather then
  codeigniter so their is nothing wrong with the database
- I have also tried to use jQuery.parseJSON so i can force it to be
  json but then the script did not run
- I used JSONlint and apprently its a valid JSON

Any help would be appreciated

Controller

```
public function insertJSON()
{
    $this->load->model("values");
    $queryresults = $this->values->getDb();

    $arrays = array($queryresults);

    echo json_encode($arrays);  
}
```

View

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

  $('#getdata').click(function (data) {

      $.ajax({

          url: '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/welcome/insertJSON';?>',
          type: 'POST',
          cache: 'false',
          datatype: 'json'

      }).done(function (data) {

         alert(data);

      });

  });

</script>
```

json_encode

```
[
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "postcode": "NW6",
        "imgurl": "hello.jpeg",
        "from_user": "henny",
        "created_at": "2013-03-18 23:03:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "postcode": "NW2",
        "imgurl": "test.jpeg",
        "from_user": "belly",
        "created_at": "2013-03-15 23:03:00"
    }
]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data[] = $arr; // <--- This $arr doesn't exist.

echo json_encode($data);
```

You are encoding a blank array. You're also not sending your array to the view properly, you shouldn't really be just echoing it.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben is right, Where is `$arr` coming from?

```
public function insert()
{

    $this->load->model("values");

    $queryresults = $this->values->Query();

    $array = array();

    foreach($queryresults as $row)
    {
        $array[] =  $row->postcode;
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
    exit; 
//    Just echo it out, no need to load view!
//    $this->load->view('answer', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The missing variable $arr should be the $array variable declared before the loop. This would do:

```
public function insert()
{

    $this->load->model("values");

    $queryresults = $this->values->Query();

    $array = array();

    foreach($queryresults as $row)
    {
        $array[] =  $row->postcode;
    }

    $data = array();

    $data[] = $array; // <--- The fix!

    echo json_encode($data);

    $this->load->view('answer', $data);
}
```

Consider double checking on your codes before doing an actual checking.